# Example of a Cartier divisor that cannot be written as the difference of effective divisors.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, blowup

Suppose $X$ is a variety and $D$ is a Cartier divisor on $X$. Fulton argues in his *Intersection theory*, that if $\pi \colon \tilde X \to X$ is the blow-up of $X$ with respect to the ideal of denominators¹ of $D$, then $\pi^* D = C - E$, where $E$ is the exceptional divisor on $\tilde X$ and $C$ is an effective Cartier divisor. So after blowing-up one can write $\pi^* D$ as the difference of two *effective* Cartier divisors.

This left me wondering: What is an example of a Cartier divisors $D$, that *cannot* be written as a difference of effective divisors on $X$ without blowing-up?

---

¹ Locally on an affine set $U = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, the ideal of denominators is defined as $I = \{a \in A : ad \in A\}$, where $d \in Q(A)$ is a local equation of $D$.

Comment: There is no such example. A divisor is by defintion a sum $D=\sum_i a_i D_i$ for integers $a_i$ and prime divisors $D_i$. Let $D_+$ be the sum of the terms in $D$ with positive coefficients, and $D_-$ be the negative of the sum of those terms with negative coefficients. Then $D_+$ and $D_-$ are effective and $D=D_+-D_-$.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti I think you are confusing Cartier and Weil divisors. A Cartier divisor is defined to be a global section of $\mathcal K^* / \mathcal O^*$, and can be given defined by giving some affine cover $U_\alpha$ and rational functions $f_\alpha$ on $U_\alpha$. What is a prime divisor in that case?

Comment: Also, why would Fulton then need to blow up?

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti Also, note that $X$ is not required to be locally factorial, so Weil divisors and Cartier divisors really might differ!

Comment: I am not confusing Cartier and Weil divisors. On any Noetherian integral scheme, in particular on any variety (at least according to my definition), every Cartier divisor has an associated Weil divisor: see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02AQ A Cartier divisor is prime if the associated Weil divisor is prime.

Comment: BUT I did mess up in the following way: I did not consider why it should be the case that if $D$ is Cartier, then $D_+$ and $D_-$ as in my comment should both be Cartier (and I do not know if it is true). So the argument in my first comment is incomplete.